# adding subviews in awakeFromNib

Tags: subviews, awakefromnib

Why does adding a subview in the awakeFromNib method cause it to go into a infinate loop? Where should subviews be added? thanks.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
     outlineViewController = [[OutlineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

     NSArray *subViews = [leftView subviews];
     if ([subViews count] > 0)
     {
         [[subViews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
     }

     [leftView addSubview:outlineViewController.view];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is due to

```
     outlineViewController = [[OutlineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

which calls initFromCoder which calls then awakeFromNib. if OutlineViewController is the same object who's awakeFromNib you posted it is so.